# Javascript: reuse bounded functions

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Standard `Function.prototype.bind` method creates a new function on each call.
I need to store somewhere and reuse bounded variants of that function.

It is not rocket science to implement function `bindArg` which works for **object arguments**:

```
const fnStorage = new WeakMap();
function bindArg(fn, arg) {
  if (!fnStorage.has(fn)) {
    fnStorage.set(fn, new WeakMap());
  }
  if (!fnStorage.get(fn).has(arg)) {
    fnStorage.get(fn).set(arg, fn.bind(null, arg));
  }
  return fnStorage.get(fn).get(arg);
}
```

this solution works fine, but only for **object arguments**. It could be done for scalar arguments by changing `WeakMap` to `Map`. But this is not good at all, because `Map` will keep reference to bounded variant of function and prevents from garbage collecting it.

Is there any way to implement `bindArg` function, which is pure immutable without memory leaking for any type of arguments?

Comment: I assume you're trying to memoize the bound functions to avoid `Function.prototype.bind`s reputation of having "bad" performance ?

Comment: No, this is for simplification of equality checking

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually doing with the code ?

Comment: I am using React with PureRenderMixin optimization. This optimization done only if props of component are not changed. Sometimes I need to pass bounded functions to component props. If I pass `fn.bind(null, arg)`, I am actually pass a new function every time. I want to reuse bounded variant of function to pass exactly the same function, if it is not changed.

Comment: **a)** unless you actually have a problem with performance, you're prematurely optimizing. **b)** mixins are old school, and this one specificaly says [Only mix into components which have simple props and state](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/pure-render-mixin.html). **c)** react 0.14 introduces [stateless functional components](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#stateless-functional-components)

Comment: **a)** Pure render technique increases my app performance **b)** I know that, actually I am using ES6 classes with [react-pure-render](https://github.com/gaearon/react-pure-render) lib, which implements same technique. My components are stateless with simple props, but these props contains callbacks. Many components contains callbacks, this is not *complex* prop. **c)** Stateless functional components [does not have](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5677) any kind of optimization yet, even pure render technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Map` for primitive data types and a `WeakMap` for objects:

```js
function isPrimitive(value) {
    return Object(value) !== value;
}

var primStore = new Map;
var objStore = new WeakMap;

function bindArg(fn, arg) {
    var store = isPrimitive(arg) ? primStore : objStore;
    if (!store.has(arg)) store.set(arg, new WeakMap);
    if (!store.get(arg).has(fn)) store.get(arg).set(fn, fn.bind(null, arg));
    return store.get(arg).get(fn);
}
```

Note that we return `store.get(arg).get(fn)` instead of `store.get(fn).get(arg)`. This flipping doesn't make any difference to the actual semantics of the `bindArg` function but it's necessary when we want to distinguish between primitive data types and objects.

---

**Edit:** Alternatively, you could create a new `WeakMap2` data structure which stores primitive values in a `Map` and objects in a `WeakMap` as follows:

```js
var WeakMap2 = defclass({
    constructor: function () {
        this.map1 = new Map;
        this.map2 = new WeakMap;

        if (arguments.length > 0) {
            for (var object in argument[0]) {
                if (isPrimitive(object))
                    throw new TypeError("Iterator value " +
                        object + " is not an entry object");
                else this.set(object[0], object[1]);
            }
        }
    },
    get: function (key) {
        return (isPrimitive(key) ? this.map1 : this.map2).get(key);
    },
    set: function (key, value) {
        return (isPrimitive(key) ? this.map1 : this.map2).set(key, value);
    },
    has: function (key) {
        return (isPrimitive(key) ? this.map1 : this.map2).has(key);
    },
    delete: function (key) {
        return (isPrimitive(key) ? this.map1 : this.map2).delete(key);
    }
});

function defclass(prototype) {
    var constructor = prototype.constructor;
    constructor.prototype = prototype;
    return constructor;
}

function isPrimitive(value) {
    return Object(value) !== value;
}
```

However, I wouldn't recommend it because it adds a layer of abstraction, making your code slower.